# Does there exist a shortest path which goes through a group of vertices U

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

The problem is finding a shortest path between two vertices in a directed graph
converting edges which enter vertices (u in U) to two edges and converting edges which enter non u vertices into 3 edges, effectively making the path through u vertices shorter than non u vertices. if there exists a shortest path of equal length which goes through all u in U.

the idea is to then run the BFS algorithm once and check whether the shortest path contains all edges in u and is of equal length to the shortest path between s and t (taking all the multiplied edges into account).

EDIT: sorry, forgot to ask the question, is this algorithm correct?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I don't see a question mark, but simply ideas/concepts. You know the method it seems like?

Comment: I fixed the post

Comment: I don't entirely understand your idea, but it does not seem to be correct. By essentially adjusting the edge weights, you make it more likely for the path to pass through U, but there is no guarantee whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: In fact it is not correct.  It is not difficult to construct a counterexample along the lines of the reasoning that I describe in my answer.  But a variation of it is correct.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could describe (even in words) a counter example, I'd rather know that my method won't work rather then to try proving it does, thanks.

Comment: Are you always trying to find a shortest path conditioned on forcing it to go through vertices in U, or are you trying to favor a 'shortest path' that actually passes through U vs ones that avoid U?

Comment: I'm trying to favor going through U, I want to find a shortest path between s and t which goes through U, so I changed the graph in order to favor going through vertices in U, I have managed to prove my algorithm since posting the question but thanks anyway, I'll write the proof in an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OP here, I've managed to prove the algorithm since posting the question.

**proof:**

if there exist shortest paths P1,P2,P3...Pn then after augmenting the graph by multiplying edges which enter non U vertices by 3 and edges which enter U vertices by 2 (I later realized the augmentation can be 2 and 1) the lengths of the shortest paths would be:
 3 * |Pi| - |{u | u in Pi}|

the number of edges in the path times 3 minus the number of vertices in the path which are in U.

clearly now the shortest path is that which minimizes 3 * |Pi| - |{u | u in Pi}|

but 3*|Pi| is a constant for all shortest paths so we actually want to maximize |{u | u in Pi}|

which means that we'll want to pass through as many vertices in u as possible so if by using BFS and recovering the shortest path we find that it doesn't contain all vertices in U we can certainly say that such a path doesn't exist, if we do find that there's a path which goes through all vertices in U we must check it's length (after restoring it to be a path in the original graph) we can simply check if it's length is the length of a shortest path between s and t if yes then it's a path which goes through all vertices in U and is a shortest path, if not then clearly it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of your algorithm can work.  Namely that you run BFS to find the shortest path, then run BFS again on an altered graph that makes it better to go through U.  BUT the way that you described altering it may shift what the best path is.

Here is the issue.  Suppose that P1 is a best path with more steps that goes through all of U, while P2 is a good path that goes through one expensive hop from U to U, before alteration P1 may be better than P2 but after you change the weights, P2 is better than P1.  And so you find P2 the second time, it doesn't go through all of U, and you wrongly conclude that P1 doesn't exist.

To fix it, you have to set a fixed reward for entering/leaving U.  Same change in all edge weights.  Now the more nodes of U that a path goes through, the better it is, but you have not changed the relative value of two paths that go through the same number of nodes of U.  And now your reasoning works with no gotchas.

Comment: you're right, I asked this question because it was a question in a test which I thought I answered correctly but the lecturer decided to grade it 2/20 points, in the test I did mention the length of the recovered path (which is very important) but I forgot to do so in this post.